# Menu items code optimization

Tags: c#, menuitem, submenu

I have a menu item that contains 5 sub-items , each one contains 4 sub-sub-items , each of them would take one new form , If i would like to code that with new form for every item that would take me 4*5 = 20 Forms !!!!

Is there any possible way where i can know the position of the selected sub-sub-item ? and then i can make only one form that makes everything

[image]

Comment: Yes.  Put all items on form then use Visible = false (or true) property for the controls.

Comment: that would just hide the item , i want to get the index of selected item or something like that so i can treat all choices in one form based on the selected item index

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the positions of a menu item from the handler, you can keep working up each owner item and finding it's position till you have a complete list of positions:

```
// Get a reference to the current item as a tool strip menu item
ToolStripMenuItem self = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

// Build a list of positions
List<int> position = new List<int>();
ToolStripMenuItem cur = self;
// Keep looping until we don't find a parent
while (cur != null)
{
    if (cur.OwnerItem is ToolStripMenuItem)
    {
        // The owner is a menu item, add it's position to our list
        ToolStripMenuItem parent = ((ToolStripMenuItem)cur.OwnerItem);
        position.Insert(0, parent.DropDownItems.IndexOf(cur));
        // And now work on the owner
        cur = parent;
    }
    else
    {
        // The owner isn't a menu item, so break out of our loop
        cur = null;
    }
}

// And as a demo, just show the positions:
MessageBox.Show("You clicked on item at " +
    string.Join(",", position.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
```